# polymorphism: why would you assign a interface reference to a subclass of superclass that implements the interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

i'm trying to understand the basics of polymorphism. 
I do understand why it could be useful to assign a superclass to a sub class or a sub to a super.

what i don't understand quite well is the logic of assigning or accessing a interface to the reference of a sub class, can someone explain why this can be usefull?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by "..assign a interface reference to a subclass of superclass that implements the interface.." but I am guessing this may be related: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947)